# Javasscript: How could I change this example to work without input field?

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I can't figure out how to change this example so that I give it a source like:
 var pdfsrc="http://www.example.com/mypdf.pdf" and it loads it on window.onload instead of user having to choose the file via input field.

Here is the code example: https://jsbin.com/geyoditona/edit?html,output

```
var input = document.getElementById("files");

                    input.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
                        file = e.target.files[0],

                        reader = new FileReader();

                        reader.onload = function () {
                            readPdf(reader.result);
                        }
                        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

                    });


                    function readPdf(buffer) {
                        PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
                        PDFJS.getDocument(buffer).then(function (pdf) {
```

Answer (score -1):

Although I am not very sure what you are exactly expecting, as far as I understand, you know the source of your pdf file, that you want to get opened directly.

If it is so, it is as simple as adding a simple anchor tag.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/mypdf.pdf">click</a>
```

You may also use _blank to open it in the next tab.

If this wasn't that simple, I am sorry to have understood wrongly. 
But if it was, cheers ;)